# onDelete cascade not working on "one to one" - Sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

My category table has a foreign key: `name_id` which is referenced to `id` of `translation` table, now category and translation have `one to one` relationship.

I would like to add a `onDelete CASCADE` so when I delete category the translation would also be deleted.

```
const Translation = sequelize.define('Translation',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      en: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
      es: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
      pt: DataTypes.STRING(1000)
    }
)

const Category = sequelize.define('Category',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      nameId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
)


Category.belongsTo(Translation, { as: 'name', foreignKey: 'nameId', onDelete: 'cascade' })
Translation.hasOne(Category, { foreignKey: 'nameId', onDelete: 'cascade' })
```

Is there something I am missing?

P.S. other tables will also be related to translations, that´s why foreign key is placed in category and not the other way around.

Comment: add hooks:true ex: { foreignKey: 'nameId', onDelete: 'cascade' ,hooks:true}

Answer (score 0):

Your association is on the wrong side! With such association definition, you will get the following scheme:

```
+----------+
| Category |
+----------+    
|    id    |
+----------+
|  nameId  |
+----------+


+-------------+
| Translation |
+-------------+ 
|     id      |
+-------------+
|     en      |
+-------------+
|     es      |
+-------------+
|     pt      |
+-------------+
|   nameId    | <-- references Category.id
+-------------+
```

Therefore, your `cascade` is working, but it will delete orphaned `Categories` when a `Translation` is dropped. To achieve what you seek, you must define your association like so:

```
Category.hasOne(Translation, { as: 'name', foreignKey: 'nameId', onDelete: 'cascade' })
Translation.belongsTo(Category, { foreignKey: 'nameId', onDelete: 'cascade' })
```

**Edit:** If you have multiple tables with translations, you need to drop the `belongTo` associations. You will only have the `hasOne` on each of these tables, ex:

```
Category.hasOne(Translation, { as: 'name', foreignKey: 'nameId', onDelete: 'cascade' });
Event.hasOne(Translation, { as: 'description', foreignKey: 'descriptionId', onDelete: 'cascade' });
```

Comment: What if as mentioned below my question I want to asign translation to other table than category too?